# Data Management in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, data-management

In an iPhone application, what is the best way to retrieve data from an online database? (either SQLite or mysql)

What i want to achieve is to read and write online data within my application.

Also,  how developers retrieve info to their apps from a server side resource (xml, json, database table etc.)?

Comment: this question is a bit vague--do you already have a remove database set up? If not, you might try something like Parse

Comment: I dont already have one, but it should be a server side database. Thats what i meant by online. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yeah--maybe check out Parse--it's a key-value back end in the cloud. I haven't used it, but sounds like just what you might need, at least to start (here: https://parse.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use REST interface to interact with online services. Check out RestKit for adding REST to your iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Dont access the database from your iOS app i discourage that, always create a RESTful layer over it, its more secure and you could benefit from the RESTful layer in lots of additional ways.